# Are there any known techniques for using separating a DLL plugin into it's own process?

Tags: c++, windows, plugins, dll

Some of our products contain a plugin DLL that is loaded by a third party application.  Some of the things we want to do in our plugin seem to conflict with the application process.  While we don't believe that our plugins have any issues even with these conflicts, whenever their applications have issues they will generally not provide support until the plugins are removed.

I'm interested in seeing if there is any way we can effectively load our plugin in its own process while still providing a seamless experience.  The DLL interface is pretty much entirely calls from the application into the plugin on certain events and an interface that the plugin can use to communicate with the application.

edit: Accidentally submitted too early...

My initial thought is to create a shim plugin DLL that spawns a separate executable that loads the actual plugin DLL.  The two processes would communicate using shared memory so the process would be something like

- Plugin callback
- Write params to shared memory
- Set event to wake process
- Process wakes and reads params and sends to actual plugin.
- Response comes back in a similar way

While this would keep everything running serially, it would unfortunately involve multiple context switches for each call which may lead to performance problems as the number of calls increases.

Comment: You can create some sort of consumer-producer algorithm that can be implemented without kernel mode synchronization primitives and less context switching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't eat your cake and eat it too. The DLL can be executed through rundll32 or something like that, but it will do nothing useful as your plugin then.

Certainly you can wrap it: if it was a COM inproc server, from the typelib you can generate an EXE server, then make its implementation using that DLL. That sounds as seamless as it gets. For regular DLLs you must provide all the interprocess stuff you'd get from COM.